# C# .Net Generic Base Class Method to return Object of that type from a json string

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

So, I am really not familiar with generics all that much or reflection but i was wondering if this is possible.

What I would like to do is have the FromString return the object that is created in the correct type from the json deserialization.

This line below

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);

I like to change to user the generic

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ***my object type*** >(str);

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    public object FromString(string str)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
    }
}
```

Then whenever I like to serialize or deserialize the object I can use those base methods.

I know I can do a GetType(this) which will give me the assembly, the name of the object as well as the namespace.

But I am at a lost as to where to go from there.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Angela

Comment: You mean you want your method signature to be `public T FromString<T>(string str)`?

Comment: Thank you David :) The T worked.  Was making it way to difficult :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use generics, it is easy like so:

```
public class BaseModel<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public T FromString<T>(string str)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
    }
}
```

You could also use a bit of reflection magic to have a non generic class:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public BaseModel FromString(string str)
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        var method = typeof(JsonConvert)
           .GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => 
          x.Name == "DeserializeObject" 
          && x.IsGenericMethod 
          && x.GetParameters().Count() == 1).MakeGenericMethod(type);
        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { str });
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
    }
}
```

Then in the second case you can just cast the result to specific model e.g.

```
var mymodel = new SpecificModel();
var result = (SpecificModel)mymodel.FromString(str);
```

Comment: A code dump answer with no explanation is usually discouraged.

Comment: The T worked... Okay feel like an idiot was trying to make it way to difficult.  ..  Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: You don't really need the class to be generic here, it can be on the method alone.

Comment: @DavidG good point. Personally i would only do that in a static class though (e.g. with extensions or so). Somehow having an instance of a non generic class with generic methods feels wrong.

Comment: Sometimes yes, but in that case, you should remove the generic type from the method as it's not needed.

Comment: DavidG, so if I took the T away from the class I would have to do FromString<T>(string) right.  So every time I call that method I have to invoke the right object?  Meaning I would have to do emp.FromString<Employee>(str) as an example?  So, what I see is by using the Generic on the class. Is that I won't have to do the <Employee> every time I call the FromString method.  Or am I missing something?